# Rails: How to send hidden paramters in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanna do this in rails way.

```
<form action="/home/result" method="GET"> 
  <input name="hidden-query" value="hidden-data" type="hidden" >
  <input name="public-query" value="public-data">
</form>
```

I tried with

```
<%= link_to 'TO RESULT',home_result_path(public_query: public_data,hidden_query: hidden_data)%>
```

It shows `hidden_query` parameter in view's url.

What I wanna do is hiding `hidden_query`.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: GET request always shows all the params in the browsers URL. Try via POST or some JS logic for redirect.

Comment: You might also want to ask yourself why you want to hide some params. Is it just to have a pretty-looking URL? If you are trying to hide something for security reasons, take a different approach. A malicious user can simply open the browser's dev tools and inspect/modify params regardless of if the request is GET, POST, or any other HTTP verb.